# How to add a IList<ItemStatusClass> in an cxisting column of DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Script For DataGridView Retrieval is:**

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
isSqlString =  "SELECT [Item] AS itemName,Status as itemStatus From Items;"
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(isSqlString, isConnStr);
da.Fill(ds1, "items");
datagridview1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["items"].DefaultView;
```

**IList:**

```
IList<ItemStatusClass> itemStatus = 
                    new List<ItemStatusClass>
                    {   
                         new ItemStatusClass { id = 0, name = "AAA" },
                         new ItemStatusClass { id = 1, name = "BBB" },
                         new ItemStatusClass { id = 2, name = "CCC" } 
                    };
```

I have added this by using below code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn statusCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
statusCol.DataPropertyName = "itemStatus";
statusCol.Name = "Status";
statusCol.ReadOnly = false;
statusCol.DataSource = itemStatus;
statusCol.DisplayMember = "name";
statusCol.ValueMember = "id";
datagridview1.Columns.Add(statusCol);
datagridview1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "itemStatus";
```

I just needed to add a **`IList<ItemStatusClass>`** to an existing column of the DataGridView.

One more column is appearing in the last of the DataGridView with the value of the Existing Column. But there is not change in Existing column, the value of the existing column is remains same. Item Code column is in Hide.

[image]

As Shown in the above image there are two **`Status`** columns are displayed. 1st status column is from SQL and second status column is which I have added programmatically.

I need the second status column has to be displayed as 2nd status column. Please let me out from this situation.

Comment: Is there an option on your DataGridView like "AutoGenerateColumn"?

Comment: Yes I have the option for my datagrigview.

Comment: I am adding before setting the datasource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the AutoGenerateColumns parameter

```
datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

then add the column that you want.

EDIT:
In your code, there are two columns in datagridview1.Columns before the column that you add.
They are created when you add the datasource with AutoGenerateColumns = true.

Check, before loading the datasource, if AutoGenerateColumns is still false.

Comment: In the Load event I am adding the line which you have put. But still I am getting the same.

Comment: Check if it is still there when you load your datasource

Comment: I am not getting the point. can you please brief.